# How to draw only one mark for one group without using encode

Tags: python, altair

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars()
```

```
alt.Chart(cars).mark_point(opacity=0.1).encode(
    x="Cylinders:O",
    y="Origin"
)
```

It draws many points at one position:

[image]

to draw only one point at one place, I need add an encode to `count()`,

```
alt.Chart(cars).mark_point(opacity=0.3).encode(
    x="Cylinders:O",
    y="Origin",
    tooltip="count()"
)
```

[image]
or by using `transform_aggregate()`, but I need set the groupby argument:

```
alt.Chart(cars).mark_point(opacity=0.4).encode(
    x="Cylinders:O",
    y="Origin",
).transform_aggregate(
    count="count()",
    groupby=["Cylinders", "Origin"]
)
```

I want to know are there any method that can do this without `transform_aggregate()` or `count()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Altair will show one point for each row of the data unless you explicitly pass an aggregate, either via an encoding or a transform.

If you want to apply an aggregate that has no effect on the chart beyond the act of aggregation, the easiest way to do so is via the `detail` channel (which roughly means "add this encoding but don't do anything with it"):

```
alt.Chart(cars).mark_point(opacity=0.4).encode(
    x="Cylinders:O",
    y="Origin:N",
    detail='count()'
)
```

[image]